# Count substring in string column using Spark dataframe

Tags: python, string, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe with a column (`assigned_products`) of type string that contains values such as the following:

```
"POWER BI PRO+Power BI (free)+AUDIO CONFERENCING+OFFICE 365 ENTERPRISE E5 WITHOUT AUDIO CONFERENCING"
```

I would like to count the occurrences of `+` in the string for and return that value in a new column.

I tried the following, but I keep returning errors.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

DF.withColumn('Number_Products_Assigned', col("assigned_products").count("+"))
```

I'm running my code in Azure Databricks on a cluster running Apache Spark 2.3.1.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's a non-udf solution. Split your string on the character you are trying to count and the value you want is the length of the resultant array minus 1:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, size, split
DF.withColumn('Number_Products_Assigned', size(split(col("assigned_products"), r"\+")) - 1)
```

You have to escape the `+` because it's a special regex character.

```
+--------------------+------------------------+
|   assigned_products|Number_Products_Assigned|
+--------------------+------------------------+
|POWER BI PRO+Powe...|                       3|
+--------------------+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 6):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,udf

@udf(returnType='int')
def cnt(s):
    return s.count('+')

DF.withColumn('Number_Products_Assigned', cnt(col("assigned_products")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace will replace the occurrence of the sub-string with null string. So we can count the occurrences by comparing the lengths before and after the replacement as follows:

### Using SparkSQL:

```
SELECT length(x) - length(replace(x,'+')) as substring_count
FROM  (select 'abc+def+ghi++aaa' as x) -- Sample data
```

**Output:**

```
substring_count
---------------
4
```

### Using PySpark functions:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = spark.sql("select 'abc+def+ghi++aaa' as x") # Sample data
df1.withColumn('substring_count', 
                F.length(col('x')) 
               - F.length(F.regexp_replace(col('x'), '\+', '')) 
              ).show()
```

**Output:**

```
+----------------+---------------+
|               x|substring_count|
+----------------+---------------+
|abc+def+ghi++aaa|              4|
+----------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

**Spark 3.4+** has [`regexp_count`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#regexp_count)

```py
F.expr(r"regexp_count(col_name, '\\+')")
```

---

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("POWER BI PRO+Power BI (free)+AUDIO CONFERENCING+OFFICE 365 ENTERPRISE E5 WITHOUT AUDIO CONFERENCING",)],
    ["assigned_products"])

df = df.withColumn('Number_Products_Assigned', F.expr(r"regexp_count(assigned_products, '\\+')"))

df.show()
# +--------------------+------------------------+
# |   assigned_products|Number_Products_Assigned|
# +--------------------+------------------------+
# |POWER BI PRO+Powe...|                       3|
# +--------------------+------------------------+
```