# pyspark count number of underscores in each row of a given column

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark version 1.5.2. I have a pyspark **dataframe** with a column "id" as shown below:

```
id
------------
000001_128
000123_1_3 
006745_8
000000_9_7
```

I want to count the number of '_' (underscores) in each row of the DF and perform a when operation such that if there is only 1 underscore in the string, I want to add '_1' as suffix, otherwise leave the value as it is. So the desired result would be :

```
id          | new_id
------------------------
000001_128  | 000001_128_1
000123_1_3  | 000123_1_3
006745_8    | 006745_8_1
000000_9_7  | 000000_9_7
```

I am using pyspark.sql.functions for other operations.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a non-udf approach:

You can use the same methodology from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51450277/5858851) to count the number of `_` in each `id`, and use [`pyspark.sql.functions.when()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) to check if the count is equal to 1. If yes, use [`pyspark.sql.functions.format_string()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.format_string) to make the `new_id`, otherwise leave the column unchanged:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn(
    "new_id",
    f.when(
        (f.size(f.split("id", "_"))-1) == 1,
        f.format_string("%s_1",f.col("id"))
    ).otherwise(f.col("id"))
).show()
#+----------+------------+
#|        id|      new_id|
#+----------+------------+
#|000001_128|000001_128_1|
#|000123_1_3|  000123_1_3|
#|  006745_8|  006745_8_1|
#|000000_9_7|  000000_9_7|
#+----------+------------+
```

Comment: I'm curious, why would using 4 UDFs (albeit built-in) passing data back and forth between dfs and regular types be better than one udf

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz it's important that these are built-ins (not user defined *python* functions) - this means that all of the execution can happen inside the JVM (pyspark is just wrapper afterall). If you want to use a python udf, spark has to serialize the dataframe so that the python code can be executed. **Update**: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38297050/5858851) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf(returnType='string')
def fmt(s):
    return s if s.count('_')!=1 else f'{s}_1'


df.withColumn('id', fmt(df.id))
```