# How to the add count of column elements in a specific column of dataset in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset as follows:

```
id   paramgroup1
1    CURRENCY=USD~COUNTRY=USA~CUSTCATEGORY=REGULAR
2    CURRENCY=USD~COUNTRY=USA~CUSTCATEGORY=GUEST
3    CURRENCY=INR~COUNTRY=IND~CUSTCATEGORY=REGULAR
```

Now i want to add a count column here which count the parameter seperated by the delimiter (~).
So the final dataset after the transformation operation of Spark,

```
 id   paramgroup1                                    count 
1    CURRENCY=USD~COUNTRY=USA~CUSTCATEGORY=REGULAR   3
2    CURRENCY=USD~COUNTRY=USA~CUSTCATEGORY=GUEST     3
3    CURRENCY=INR~COUNTRY=IND                        2
```

Any help would be appreciated....

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51450004/spark-dataframe-python-count-substring-in-string/51450277#51450277

Answer (score 0):

```
//in scala,
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df1 = df.withColumn("count", size(split($"paramgroup1", "~")))
df1.show()
```

Comment: Assumes at least one entry in that field.